# Ping Federate IDP-SP Implementation

Tags: pingfederate

I am a newbie on PingFederate. Able to setup PingFederate locally. I just got another thought. Suppose i am setting up PingFederate as SP. Now the other party(IDP) will send me SAML only. I guess since there is no PingFederate at IDP side, there is no open token and we couldnt use any Integration Kits in that case.

Now the IDP sends **SAML** to PingFederate. Should be to any endpoints.  Am i right?  (If someone knows about this, please detail)

In this case how would PingFederate as an SP extract userinformation ? (I understand that it accepts opentoken only)

Please throw some light in to this issue.

Kindly provide any links which could be helpful in understanding more on PingFederate..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, full disclosure: I work for Ping. ;)

You're correct in stating that when you're the SP, you'll receive an assertion in some standard protocol, like SAML, but there are others, too. I won't talk about those - don't need to muddy the waters just yet!

So, within SAML, a number of attributes can be passed as part of the assertion. At a minimum, you will ALWAYS have the subject, which would be the user ID, email, whatever, that is what you and the IdP have agreed upon as the identifier for the user. But, you could get other things too, by extending the contract of the assertion, to things like first/last names, phone numbers, etc., whatever the IdP may have for you to utilize (especially for instantiating a new user in your SP side!).

So, you get the attribute(s) in the assertion, then you push those to your SP application - quite possibly via openToken (since we provide the openToken adapter, it's pretty easy to integrate that into your app), or maybe you use our .net or Java SDKs.

I would *highly* recommend heading over to our library of free videos on training. You can check them all out here:
https://www.pingidentity.com/support/training-center/

Start with an intro to federation: https://www.pingidentity.com/support/training-center/training-video.cfm/introduction-to-federation?id=1017466745001

Then you'll have some basics under your belt, and can move on into the other areas, especially the TRT sections where you can learn to build adapters, use the HTML Form Adapter that we include, connect to LDAP directories and Databases as user stores... All sorts of good stuff.

And if you're a paying customer (or even not yet - you're just kicking the tires!), if you get REALLY stuck, you can contact our support team.

Happy federating!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have gone through the videos and i have a good basic undestanding. My question is on usage on ACS.saml2 endpoint. I am working in .net and so i use it to implement Federation. Can you give me a piece of code on how to use the endpoint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry I missed your response, Bonnie. You don't use that endpoint directly. Well, you could, but the work is already done for you. Just use our OpenToken integration kits (you got them for free when you purchased). Those will allow your PingFed to pass attributes via OpenToken to your application.